# how to keep values in textfields after submitting a form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form to filter data as per the entered from and to date. Everything is working fine but I just want that values should be keep in textfields.
I tried as -
view -

```
<form action="{{url('user/manage')}}" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="From" name="from_date" value="{{old('from_date')}}" id="from_date" class="form-control">
<input type="text" placeholder="To" name="to_date" value="{{old('to_date')}}" id="to_date" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" value="Filter" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter E mail" name="email_search" id="" value="{{old('email_search')}}" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
<input type="submit" value="Show" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Controller -

```
$values=[];
$values['from_date']=$from;  
$values['to_date']=$to;  
return view('show',['users'=>$users])->withInput($values);
```

Please Help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Input data is stored in the session between requests. Are you redirecting after a request has processed, or are you trying to maintain inputs in the case a request is not validated, i.e. redirected back to the page with error messages?

In the first case you can use `$request->session()->flash()` to keep the data in the session after the request has processed.

In the second case, data is flashed automatically and accessible through the `old()` helper method, as you have in your form example.

Answer (score 4):

> try this. your form and controller method should be like

// **form**

```
<form action="{{url('user/manage')}}" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From" name="from_date" value="{{$from_date}}" id="from_date" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="To" name="to_date" value="{{$to_date}}" id="to_date" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E mail" name="email_search" id="" value="{{old('email_search')}}" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Show" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
```

// **controller**

```
$data = [
 'users'=>$users,
'from_date'=>$from, 
'to_date'=>$to;  ]
return view('show',$data); 
]
```

Comment: You can also pass your request variable when returning a view from your controller.

`return view('your.view',$request); //->with('extraValues',$extraValues');`